# Bash - Awk sort -n not sorting

Tags: linux, bash

```
awk '{for(i=1; i<=NF; i++) printf("%d ",$i)}' | sort -n
```

it reads a file like

```
55 89 33 20
```

and prints it out normally, not numerically sorted. Why?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`sort` works on a per-line basis, and `printf` doesn't append a newline by default, you need to specify it. So use:

```
awk '{for(i=1; i<=NF; i++) printf("%d\n",$i)}' | sort -n
```

This will print out your numbers on separate lines, if you want them to be in a single line again then you can pipe it to `paste`:

```
awk '{for(i=1; i<=NF; i++) printf("%d\n",$i)}' | sort -n | paste -s -d ' '
```

You can also just use print instead of printf, this will append the newline by default:

```
awk '{for(i=1; i<=NF; i++) print $i}' | sort -n
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to keep the numbers all on one line but sort them, you can also just do the sorting in `awk` itself.

```
$ awk '{split($0,f,FS); n=asort(f); 
     for (i=1; i<=n; ++i) printf("%d ", f[i]); printf "\n"}' <<<'55 89 33 20'
20 33 55 89
```

But this is starting to get into territory where I reach for Perl instead, just because it's a shorter program to write at the shell prompt:

```
$ perl -lane 'print join " ",sort @F' <<<'55 89 33 20'
20 33 55 89
```

Awk is more expressive in many cases, but array operations are not one of them.

Ruby is about as short, if you prefer a language that was cool more recently than Perl :) :

```
$ ruby -lane 'puts $F.sort.join " "' <<<'55 89 33 20'
20 33 55 89
```

Even Python, which is not exactly built for one-liners, is less code than Awk in this case (but the same number of parentheses):

```
$ python -c 'print " ".join(sorted(raw_input().split()))' <<<'55 89 33 20'
20 33 55 89
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting the file as per your example:

```
echo "55 89 33 20" > file.txt
```

The following command will output what you want:

```
awk '{for(i=1; i<=NF; i++) print($i)}' file.txt | sort -n
20
33
55
89
```

Note that `print` will print a new line character each time.
Also, note that the filename should be passed as an argument to `awk`.

Answer (score 0):

a solution without `awk` :

```
cat file | sed 's/ /\n/g' | sort -n | paste -s -d ' '
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: OP said "with awk", so technically this is answering a different question. But if OP is happy, then no problem. Maybe worth changing original question text in that case.

Comment: True, technically, OP asked why `awk` was behaving the way it is, not how to solve the problem. We SO types just like to solve problems even when not asked to, I guess. :)

Comment: @ChrisBallard see **Answer the question** in http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: I saw the above in the `Low Quality Post` review queue, but probably there just because it seems short. Clearly I was too harsh this time as no one else flagged or downvoted. Apologies.